# spring-data-orientdb lacks on OrientGraphFactory autoconfigure?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data, orientdb, graph-databases

I've found [spring data orientdb](https://github.com/orientechnologies/spring-data-orientdb) project and done some tests.

I need to work with graph API and noticed that on spring boot autoconfigure module the OrientGraphFactory is not initialized.

Any suggestions? thanks

Comment: It's still in snapshot. So, It's not production ready.